# Invalid WPF name?

Tags: c#, wpf

Can someone please explain to me why this name is invalid?

'stackPanelOneZeroZeroPercentBasicBuybackStartNormalBracketMotorplusEndNormalBracket StartNormalBracketOneEightZeroOneEndNormalBracketStartNormalBracketUnderwrittenEndNormalBracket' is not a valid value for property 'Name'.

Comment: Really asking out of curosity, why do you have such a name? Isn't it a bit... long and difficult to read?

Comment: thats one hell of a long name - and whats the "EndNormalBracket" "StartNormalBracket" bits in it for.. it reads like the name was stackpanel10%basicbuyback(motorplus)(180)(underwritten)

Comment: Probably testing some kind of Algo that turns invalid name characters into readable names.

Comment: Hi, The name is long because as Manfred RadIwimmer said, we were doing Algo to turn invalid characters into valid names. BugFinder is correct, but there is an extra 0 ;) its 100%.

Comment: Thank you god, I was worried this was actually somebody's naming convention.

Comment: Where is this identifier being used?  Is it in a XAML file or in a .cs file?

Comment: Hi Chris, This is in a .cs file. We corrected the problem by updating the name in our database, we literally just typed it word for word and made sure the was only one *Space* between the word, after we updated it that way it worked fine in the system. So we don't really know what was wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of the space in the middle (after `EndNormalBracket`)

```
stackPanelOneZeroZeroPercentBasicBuybackStartNormalBracketMotorplusEndNormalBracket StartNormalBracketOneEightZeroOneEndNormalBracketStartNormalBracketUnderwrittenEndNormalBracket
                                                                              here ^
```

Other than that, there is (technically) nothing wrong with it.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the advice, i added the following code to combat these instances:

toReturn = toReturn.Replace(" ", "Space");
toReturn = toReturn.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "New Line");

But it is still throwing that exception.

Comment: @ebenzandberg so first you replace all spaces by the word space and then you replace newlines by a small sentence with a space in it? That means it still contains a space if there is a newline in it! Swap those lines or replace a new line with "NewLine"

Comment: Hahaha, i see that, but ok so i made an edit and removed the space between NewLine AS WELL and its still throwing the exception, so we are suspecting it might be a TAB?